# Nested subsetting with "["

Tags: r, subset

I recently discovered that, after subsetting an object (i.e. a data frame) with "[", the resulting object could be subset with "[" on the same line of code (I should have realized it earlier!). Here is an example:

```
# Create a data frame
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))

# Take a look at the data frame
df1
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9

# If I want the value which is on the 3rd row and 2nd column
df1[3,2]
[1] 6

# But I could also
df1[,2][3]
[1] 6
```

A few words on the second alternative. `df[,2]` returns an atomic vector, which is then subset with `df[,2][3]`.

The following data frame will be helpful to illustrate my issue. It is a simple data frame containing the name of 26 students, their respective department as well as a numeric value. A seed number is added for reproducibility.

```
set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame(name = letters, dept = sample(c("econ", "stat", "math"), 26, replace = TRUE), value = runif(26, 0, 100))
head(df2)
  name dept    value
1    a econ 54.40660
2    b math 59.41420
3    c stat 28.91597
4    d math 14.71136
5    e math 96.30242
6    f econ 90.22990
```

***I would like to know who has the lowest value in the `econ` department.*** The first thing I tried was:

```
df2[df2$dept == "econ" & df2$value == min(df2$value),]
[1] name  dept  value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

It took me a while to understand what I was doing wrong, but I finally realized that the problem was that my code assumed that the person who had the lowest value overall was also from the `econ` department, which is not the case (and that's the answer that `R` gave me). Actually, the person with the lowest value overall is from the `stat` department.

```
i <- which(df$value == min(df$value))
df[i,]
  name dept    value
9    i stat 2.461368
```

Of course, I can easily find the answer to my question with:

```
df_econ <- df2[df2$dept == "econ",]
df_econ
   name dept    value
1     a econ 54.40660
6     f econ 90.22990
15    o econ 14.28000
17    q econ 41.37243
18    r econ 36.88455
19    s econ 15.24447
df_econ[df_econ$value == min(df_econ$value),]
   name dept value
15    o econ 14.28
```

But I would like to know if I can get the same result using "nested" subsetting with the `[` operator. What I mean is with a code like this:

```
df2[df2$dept == "econ",][... ,]
```

I do not know how to refer to the `value` column at this point since the resulting data frame of the first subsetting operation `df2[df2$dept == "econ",]` is a data frame different from `df2`. I also know that the `value` column is the 3rd column, but I do not know how to set subsetting conditions using column indexes rather than their names.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: FWIW `data.table`s are excellent for this type of operation.

Comment: You'd need chaining for this, which means package data.table or package dplyr.

Comment: @nrussell Thank you for the recommendation. I am more familiar with the `dplyr` package, but is there no way to do it in base R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some options:

```
library(dplyr) 
# also in @bramtayl's answer:
df2 %>% filter(dept == "econ") %>% filter(value==min(value))
# or
df2 %>% filter(dept == "econ") %>% slice(which.min(value))

# or...

library(data.table) 
setDT(df2)[dept == "econ"][value==min(value)]
# or
setDT(df2)[dept == "econ"][which.min(value)]
```

These packages offer convenient ways of chaining not available in base R except awkwardly, like

```
subset(subset(df2, dept=="econ"), value == min(value))
```

There may be other packages, but these two are widely used lately.

---

*Comment.* If you're just browsing data, I'd recommend aggregating at the `dept` level:

```
# dplyr:
df2 %>% group_by(dept) %>% slice(which.min(value))

# data.table:
df2[, .SD[which.min(value)], by=dept]


   dept name     value
1: econ    o 14.280002
2: math    t 13.880606
3: stat    i  2.461368
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Well, now I know that this is impossible in base R.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed that chaining is necessary:

```
library(magrittr)

df %>%
  `[`(.$dept == "econ", ) %>%
  `[`(.$value == min(.$value), )
```

Why not stick with dplyr though?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(dept == "econ") %>%
  filter(value == min(value) )
```